# All-in-one administration

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have several forum-like models (forum, thread, post...) defined and related by foreign keys. They are all registered in the admin interface via admin.py, but they have to be managed separately.

What I mean is that I would like to be able to go, for example, into the "threads" admin menu, open a thread's details, and manage that thread AND all the posts belonging to that thread from that one place.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) that fits yours needs, since you didn't say in your question I'm assuming that you don't have nested posts, things will get harder if you do have nesting.

But keep in mind that this will greatly increase the number of database queries, every object that is related with the parent and is rendered will use a new queryset to populate the interface, that means that every foreign key will have a new query.